# Правильно указать окончание причастия

Tags: причастия

Выдержка из Партнерского Соглашения:
Партнер обязуется:
- Заключать Договора по тарифам и услугам, указанных (ым) в Приложении #1 к настоящему Партнерскому Соглашению.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

*Выдержка из Партнерского Соглашения: Партнер обязуется: - Заключать Договора по тарифам и услугам,(каким?) указанным в Приложении #1 к настоящему Партнерскому Соглашению.*

Comment: Это самый очевидный ответ, иначе я бы не задавал этот вопрос. По- моему мнению, по правилам звучит как-то косноязычно. Почему нельзя задать вопрос: - По тарифам и услугам (каких?, именно каких?), указанных в Приложении #1 ?

Comment: Radiy Satuchin, нет тарифов и услуг - каких? А *по* - предлог дательного падежа: дам тарифам и услугам - каким? И не "договора", а договор***ы***.

Comment: Насчёт договорА уже выяснили :)) В данном контексте все правильно. ДоговорЫ могут быть только между странами, а между двумя коммерческими субъектами - договорА.

Comment: "Ваш" дательныый падеж уже надоел, честное слово! Вопрос именно в косноязычности высказывания: тарифам и услугам не "указывали там быть", они там были "по умолчанию изначально"!

Comment: Я помогла Вашему вопросу - гляньте в поле "Основная часть".

Answer (score 1):

*Заключать Договор**ы** по тарифам и услугам, **указанным…***

Причастие **указанные** должно стоять в том же числе и падеже, что и существительные **тарифы** и **услуги** (мн. ч.). Давайте разбираться:

И. п. — что? тарифы, услуги; какие? указанные;
Р. п. — чего? тарифов, услуг; каких? указанных;
**Д. п. — чему? тарифам, услугам; каким? указанным;**
В. п. — что? тарифы, услуги; какие? указанные;
Т. п. — чем? тарифами, услугами; какими? указанными;
П. п. — о чём? тарифах, услугах; каких? указанных.

Падежные окончания причастия зависят от вопроса и совпадают с окончаниями вопроса, который мы можем поставить от существительных.

[Склонение причастий](https://videouroki.net/video/2-sklonieniie-prichastii-pravopisaniie-ghlasnykh-v-padiezhnykh-okonchaniiakh-prichastii.html)

P. S. Большой орфоэпический словарь признал допустимым в бытовом общении ударение «дОговор», форма множественного числа «договорА» в нем по-прежнему отмечена как неправильная.

Comment: Я не спорю против правил!  Я не лингвист и не учитель русского языка, но в то же время в школьное время "имел честь" участвовать в олимпиадах по русскому языку.

Comment: Но иногда, как сейчас, мне режет слух конкретный оборот: указанным чему-то там-то быть , хотя они там уже были до этого

Comment: Вполне возможно, что им (тарифам и услугам) даже не "указывали там  быть", а они сами по своей воле согласились там быть :))

Comment: Не нравится "указанным" — напишите перечисленным, установленным. Можно много синонимов подобрать.